# Viewing a local web site on the LAN under a different hostname

Tags: iphone, macos, dns, nginx, bonjour

In short I'm trying to browse a Mac's web site on the local wifi network under a `.local` hostname that is not the same as the machine's 'computer name' and think I'm missing a setup step.

I have a local install of nginx on my Macbook, with the proper `/etc/hosts` and `nginx.conf` entries to serve multiple sites, each with their own distinct local hostname. Assume the Macbook's network name is computername.local, and I have 2 sites running, one at http://computername.local and another at http://servicename.local. I can access each of these sites just fine from the local machine, but also want to be able to access http://servicename.local from an iPhone on the same WiFi network. I'm getting a timeout for that URL, but the other one works just fine.

I'm guessing something has to be done to allow servicename.local to be used on the local network, which I've left out. What is required to do that? Do I need to use Bonjour for that? Where would I add this new local hostname?

Another Mac on the same network can access this one under servicename.local just fine if I define the IP in its `/etc/hosts` file too, but I can't modify that file on the iPhone obviously. It's not jailbroken, and I'm not really interested in doing that just to get this working.

Comment: You will need to have some DNS entry to point the http://servicename.local to the IP of the other machine. Not sure how you do this on an iPhone.

Comment: @Rasika: I imagine I could run a local DNS server on the network and define DNS there. I just assumed that one of the features of Bonjour was to advertise the availability of a particular service on the network under different hostnames, so I didn't have to resort to a local name server.

Comment: I'm not sure how Bonjour works, but it could be that it only advertises one host name for the service which is the machine name. There may be some setting in there to change this name. Don't have a Mac here to test this.

Comment: This is just another hunch, but I guess that the actual app for the service needs to utilize some kind of Bonjour API, and that nginx simply doesn't support it, so I'm checking if there's a MacOS X specific file I can edit myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will help the OP, but another way of doing this - besides running a DNS server or jailbreaking the phone - is to run an HTTP proxy on the Mac, and configure the iPhone to use the proxy. Then the iPhone will pick up the Mac's local hosts file entries because it resolves DNS queries through the proxy. I've blogged about how to do this using the free Mac proxy "SquidMan" here: http://egalo.com/99j